# Adding comments to data structure in API Blueprint

Tags: data-structures, markdown, apiblueprint, apiary.io

I have two properties, one of which must be supplied. I was trying to add a comment at the bottom of the data structure but it was ignored. So I tried a multi line description but that was also ignored:

```
# Data Structures

## Record (object)

+ ResponseId: `42f7b8b07da641bcb6d96422cb903c0e` (string, optional) - Identifier for the record being updated
+ UniqueReference: 1 (number, optional) - Reference for the record being updated.

    If both are supplied, response id will be used
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the description to the top and use [member type separator](https://github.com/apiaryio/mson/blob/master/MSON%20Specification.md#421-member-type-separator) to separate it from the member properties.

Eg.

```
# Data Structures

## Record (object)

If both are supplied, response id will be used

### Properties

- ResponseId: 42f7b8b07da641bcb6d96422cb903c0e (string, optional) - Identifier for the record being updated
- UniqueReference: 1 (number, optional) - Reference for the record being updated.
```

Comment: Unless I did something wrong, that didn't appear to work.

`FORMAT: 1A
HOST: http://test.apiblueprint.org/

# Test

## Backfeed [/api/Backfeeds]

### Single backfeed record [PUT]

+ Attributes (BackfeedRecord)

+ Request (application/json)

        {
          "UniqueReference": 4
        }

+ Response 202

# Data Structures

## BackfeedRecord (object)

If both are supplied, response id will be used
    
### Properties

+ ResponseId: 42f7b8b07 (string, optional) - Identifier for the record being updated
+ UniqueReference: 1 (number, optional) - The reference for the record being updated.`

Comment: @sixeyes can you please paste the blueprint in an answer or use a gist to link it

Comment: the blueprint looks OK, it is the bug in rendering – check https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/191